# Securely generate a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, uniqueidentifier, cryptography

I intend to be using a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` as an access key that users can use to access certain data. The key will act as a password in that sense.

I need to generate multiple such identifiers as part of an `INSERT...SELECT` statement. For architectural reasons I want to generate the identifiers server-side in this case.

How can I generate a securely random `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`? Note, that `NEWID` would not be random enough as it does not promise any security properties at all. I'm looking for the SQL Server equivalent of [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) because I need unguessable IDs. Anything based on `CHECKSUM`, `RAND` or `GETUTCDATE` would also not qualify.

Comment: Have you run NEWID() in a loop 1000 times? Do you see any evidence that any of these values have become guessable?

Comment: @AaronBertrand at the very least, one if the digits is always `4`. But the fact that I don't have strong evidence that they might be guessable does not mean that they are not. I cannot base this security decision on this observation.

Comment: One of the digits on my machine is always 4 too. That doesn't make the other 31 characters all that much easier to guess. *shrug*

Comment: Maybe NEWID is just as random as the "Debian weak SSH keys": http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Predictable_random_number_generator_discovered_in_the_Debian_version_of_OpenSSL They certainly looked random to the developer who tested them...

Comment: and maybe CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM is just as random too.

Comment: The docs guarantee that it is strongly random (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx). It is the standard way to generate securely random bytes on Windows.

Comment: Related and maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643445/how-easily-can-you-guess-a-guid-that-might-be-generated

Comment: @usr: The docs that Microsoft provides. So the claim is as valid as your trust in Microsoft. You can always `XOR` any random source with other random source(s) though, even my clumsy and not-so-strong random generator or the [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com/221/) one: `int GetRandom() {return 4;}`. You lose nothing, except speed.

Comment: That 4 tells you what algorithm is used in generating the GUID.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm

Comment: You do understand that the only determining factor in the level of your security is the bit entropy?  The idea that NEWID is not random enough for your needs would imply that you have some idea of the amount of bit entropy which is required to be "secure" for your use case.  What is that number?

Comment: @CadeRoux that number is 128 bits. I will not take the chance with the NEWID generator which might well be the linear congruential generator from the C standard library (at most 32 bits of entropy in it - I don't even want to know how it was seeded). Why take the chance if high security is just a function call away? Also note, that I'm generating many such keys. I don't want one key to give away all other keys.

Comment: Oh I'm just seeing this: "Cryptanalysis of the WinAPI GUID generator shows that, since the sequence of V4 GUIDs is pseudo-random, **given full knowledge of the internal state, it is possible to predict previous and subsequent values**." So much for "yeah NEWID is probably enough..."!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757910/how-are-net-4-guids-generated

Comment: @usr - "given full knowledge of the internal state", one can crack *any* approach.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Should do the trick I would have thought.

[`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx)

> Returns a cryptographic random number generated by the Crypto API
>   (CAPI).

Comment: [This answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059933/696808) might be a better general solution since it actually tries to conform to the UUIDv4 structure.

Answer (score 6):

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/23/newsequentialid-histrorybenefits-and-implementation/, the NEWID() function just wraps the Windows function CoCreateGuid, which returns a v4-style GUID. And according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417a2c-7a58-404f-84dd-6b494ecf0d13#id11, since Windows 2000 back in 1999,

> "the random bits for all version 4 GUIDs built in Windows are obtained
>   via the Windows CryptGenRandom cryptographic API or the equivalent,
>   the same source that is used for generation of cryptographic keys"

So I'd say you could consider NEWID() cryptographically secure -- at least to the extent of the 122 bits of entropy it provides.

Comment: That's interesting. I personally would not trust this for security purposes. Neither Windows nor SQL Server make a guarantee about this.

Comment: @usr I'm not sure what a guarantee would look like. It doesn't use the word "guarantee", but it appears to be standard MSDN Windows SDK documentation. It would be extremely unlikely for MS to downgrade the cryptographic randomness of GUIDs in some future version of Windows. There would be nothing to gain.

Comment: That MSDN page merely documents historic choices but it does not say that this will be kept in the future. Same for SQL Server. I cannot imagine circumstances under which this would break down. But there have been many catastrophic RNG debacles. Assumptions like this one have often turned out false. It's a heuristic argument.

Comment: @usr But how could any MSDN documentation *guarantee* future behavior of Windows? The most we can ever hope for in these cases is documentation of the current behavior. If the behavior ever changes, well then they update the documentation. That's why these Stack Overflow Q&As have version tags and get updated from time to time.

Comment: They do make guarantees about things they will not change. They could change the product but they won't if they say "here's a security critical function with these properties". I interpret that documentation in question more like a historic view than a statement about the future.

Answer (score 4):

Just my two cents, but this may not be a good idea. To paraphrase Eric Lippert's excellent series on GUID's ([part 1](https://ericlippert.com/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one/), [part 2](https://ericlippert.com/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two/), [part 3](https://ericlippert.com/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three/)), the acronym is GUID, not GSUID - Globally Unique Identifier, not Globally Secure Unique Identifier.

The problem lies in that when GUIDs are generated within a non-hostile scope, such as everyone using NEWID(), all values are guaranteed to be unique (well, sort of, see Eric's article, part 3).  But if a hostile entity enters that scope, they can both predict the next generated GUID, as well as cause collisions on their own.

By creating your own method of generating a value that you store inside a structure that looks like a GUID, you have essentially become a hostile entity.  You have changed the contract of a GUID from being *unique* to being *random*.  While someone better at math than I could probably prove you are still unique, that is only within the confines of your generation method.  If you mix these pseudo-GUIDs with NEWID() GUIDs, all bets are off.

I say this *may* not be a good idea only because I don't know the entire scope of how you are using the values.  If you are the only entity generating the values (no mix and match), and/or you aren't persisting the values, and/or you don't care about collisions, this may not be an issue.  If any of those items aren't true, you may want to re-evaluate.

Comment: Interesting points. My data type choice `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is mostly a coincidence. It is just convenient to handle a 16 byte quantity using that type. I think of it as a password. It has to be unique, though. I'm confident that I will never see a collision (and even if there is the app will just crash - so that's safe, too).

Comment: I disagree, it depends 'how' you encrypt it to if it becomes random rather than unique. It can easily be the same.